# Comma to resolve ambiguity with relative clause

Tags: punctuation, ambiguity, free-relative-clauses

Does the below sentence make sens from the grammatical point of view ?

What you think is important, is very important, is extremly important.

- the comma "," is as a vehicle to determine the scope of subject

Comment: I think the commas don't help. However, this is possible, *"What she thinks he thinks you think is important is very important is extremely important."* But nobody would really say it, unless they wanted to have some fun with words.

Comment: I don't see nested relative clauses here.. I see a subject with three predicates (if I'm correct in the terminology).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What you think is important, is very important, is extremly important.

- There is no nesting of relative clauses here. There is only one relative clause, and it is not an ordinary *bound relative clause* acting as a modifier but a *free* (or *fused*) *relative clause* acting as subject of the sentence.
- The sentence does make sense. Its problem is that it makes ***too much*** sense: it can be understood in two different ways, depending on the role of the first *is important*: is that a predicate on the subject or a constituent of the subject, a complement on *think*?

  1. If the free relative clause is *What you think*, meaning “your thought, your opinion”, then the sentence has (as CopperKettle understands it) three predicates, linked without conjunctions (this is a fairly common rhetorical device called [*asyndeton*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asyndeton)):

     ```
     [What you think] is important, 
             (AND IT) is very important, 
             (AND IT) is extremely important.
     ```

     We would understand this to mean

     > Your opinion is important; not only that, it is **very** important; indeed it is **extremely** important.
  2. But the free relative clause may be *What you think is important*, meaning “the matter which you think is important”. In that case there are only two predicates:

     ```
     [What you think is important] is very important, 
                          (AND IT) is extremely important.
     ```

     We would understand this to mean

     > The matter which you think is important is in fact very important; not only that, it is extremely important.

  The comma after the first *important* suggests that 1 is what is meant; but it is not uncommon for writers to insert a comma in this position in sentences like 2: the comma stands for the natural pause we take in speech to mark what precedes it as a distinct syntactic unit.